# I can't access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/ on Mac

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin

I have followed the instructions on this [link](http://server.ws.dp.ua/install-phpmyadmin-yosemite-osx-10-10/)
I also checked few other tutorials and they've shown similar configurations.

i tried those urls : http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/
                     http://localhost/~macbookpro/phpmyadmin/setup/

Any help ?

Comment: Have you activated Web Sharing?

Comment: No. Is it necessary?  how do i do it ?

Comment: What's your OSX version?

Comment: OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite)

Comment: They removed the option after 10.6.x, but you can still do it this way (http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-web-sharing-in-os-x-mountain-lion/)